# Alignment problems in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I'm Trying to get the buttons to go under the white box. In the java file I am adding a special view to the id:ViewLayout. I have tried putting the buttons after the Framelayout, but they dont appear on screen....

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvClock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="12:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="100dp" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bUnlock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Unlock" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PIN" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvClock"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="12:00"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:textSize="100dp" />

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/Container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/ViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bUnlock"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Unlock" 
    android:layout_below="@id/ViewLayout"
 />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bPin"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PIN" 
    android:layout_below="@id/bUnlock"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Try `RelativeLayout` instead of `framelayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvClock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="12:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="100dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.58" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvClock"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="12:00"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="2" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bUnlock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unlock" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPin"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="PIN" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```